# Is Swapnote initially installed internally?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

The Nintendo 3DS XL comes with [Swapnote preinstalled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swapnote). Is it preinstalled on the internal memory? Or is it on the included SD card?

I know it can be deleted via Data Management, so it's not built-in to the system and has to be stored somewhere.

I can't test because I deleted (and later redownloaded it) already, and it definitely downloads to the SD card when done manually.

Comment: Curious as to why you'd want to know this.  It's a pretty pointless piece of software since they removed the ability to send notes via spotpass.

Comment: @Mkalafut I still use it to send notes to friends StreetPass

Comment: True true @Batophobia

Comment: @Batophobia Well if you're close enough to your friends to tag them on street pass, why wouldn't you just.. talk to them?  It seems to be that any usefulness that Swapnote had died when they removed Spotpass.  Which by the way, does anyone know if they plan to bring it back?

Comment: @Mkalafut I like to make little drawings or short comic strips for them.  The benefit is that I can do it in my down time and, after passing relatively close by, they can receive it and read at their convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Swapnote is 3DSWare, so it saves to the SD card if you download it from the store, like all 3DSWare. The system only saves certain applications to the system memory. And before anyone points out the DSiWare installs to the internal memory, DSiWare installs to the internal memory and can be moved to the SD *but can't be run from the SD card*. **EDIT**: The 3DS titles and 3DSWare can be played from the SDCard, which is why the system saves them there. DSiWare is designed NOT to play from the SD card but from internal memory. So that's why it will save directly to system memory.

Whether or not Swapnote is installed to system memory is... hard to say. Most items that you start with are saved to your system memory, so I assume Swapnote is as well, considering that I never uninstalled SwapNote but I can take out my SD card and still have it (none of my messages, though). But just so you know, items in the internal memory aren't permanent-- you can move data into and out of system memory no problem, you just can't delete some items (Face Raiders, for example). I doubt the manufacturing process involves downloading software-- it probably comes in your system memory initially because they would be placing it with a bunch of other 3DSWare.

But after you delete it, since you can only get it from the eShop it, like all other 3DSWare titles, will save to the SDCard.